# Reverse for 'customerdel' with arguments '('',)' not found.1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/records/customerdel/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django, database, object, model

I am trying to delete an object from database using simple html button. Also, trying to implement "are you sure" message? BUt I am getting this error everytime and I am not able to crack.

This is my view function.

```
    def customerdel(request,pk):
        objs = Customer.objects.filter(id=pk)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            objs.delete()
            # messages.success(request, 'Successfully deleted')
            return render(request,'records.html')

        else:
            content ={
             'items':Customer.objects.all
            }
            return render(request,'delete.html', content)
```

This is record.html page

```
<h1>Record's page</h1>

{% for abc in Customerdata %}
{{abc.name}}
{{abc.pk}}


<form >
    <button  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
    <a href="{% url 'customerdel' abc.pk %}">Delete</a></button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

This is delete.html page

```
<h1>Welcome to Delete page</h1>


<p>Are you sure want to del {{items.name}} ??</p>
<form action="{% url 'customerdel' items.pk %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <a href="{% url 'records' %}">Cancel</a>
    <input name="confirm" type="submit" >

</form>
```

This is my URL.

```
path('dashboard/records/customerdel/<int:pk>', views.customerdel, name='customerdel'),
```

Comment: You did not send any context to the template, so `Customerdata` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong while template rendering as you are not sending any data to the template.But inside the record.html you are trying to iterate over CustomerData which is not defined.So send it to the template or another way is to simply redirect to the route which is made for rendering record.html.

Here is the full code which you should apply in your django project to make it work.

```
from django.http import HttpresponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse #these two lines are required for redirecting to a previous route(url)
```

As you must have set a url which takes to the records function something like this;

```
path('records', views.records, name='records')
```

If you haven't added the name, add it.

Then in views.py, in customerdel function;

```
if request.method == 'POST':
#write your code which you already wrote and instead of return render(...) write this;
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('records')) #where records is the name of the url which takes us to the records page.
```

Comment: This is my record.html which has Customerdata defined.                                                                           def records(request):
    content = {
        'Orderdata' : Order.objects.all(),
        'Customerdata': Customer.objects.all(),
        'Prodcutdata': Customer.objects.all(),
        'Tagdata': Customer.objects.all(),

    }

    return render(request, 'records.html', content)

Comment: That is what i am saying.You defined it in the function records but when you render record.html again in the "if request.method == 'POST'" you didn't define it again.

Comment: As i mentioned in the answer, you can also use redirect in costumerdel function instead of rendering record.html as;  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('name_of_the_route_which_takes_to_records'))